# Deeplinking Within Flexslider (or any slider)

Tags: jquery, slider, flexslider

I want to add deeplinking into flexslider..

The ability to click on a specific link:

```
<a href="#contact">whatever text..</a>
```

id, and it will take me to the specific slider li. Is this possible? e.g.

```
<ul>
    <li id="title">...</li>
    <li id="title2">...</li>
    <li id="title3">...</li>
    <li id="contact">...</li>
</ul>
```

-Neil

Answer (score 0):

Use the JavaScript's `window.location.hash`. Use any of these:

1. `var hash = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];`
2. `var hash = $(this).attr('href').replace(/^.*?#/,'');`
3. `var hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(test.indexOf('#')+1);`
4. `var hash = $(this).attr('href').match(/#(.*$)/)[1];`

Use this code then:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
$("#" + hash).show();
```

This will show the particular `div` from the given URL. You can take this code as a reference:

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $("#hash").html(hash);
    $("div").removeClass("selected");
    $(hash).addClass("selected");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#one">One</a>
<a href="#two">Two</a>

<div id="one">One</div>
<div id="two">Two</div>
<div id="hash"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.selected {background: #ff0;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/F2whf/